# How to check a value against a flat file

Tags: javascript, web-applications

What's the fastest way to do the following on a web page:

Given a string value, check it against a flat file stored a server and return true if it is found and false otherwise. The file contain < 5k lines where each line contains no more than 20 characters.

Is this something that can be done entirely on the client-side? If possible, I would rather not involve a database.

Comment: How much time do you have?

Comment: Does the file have to be secure? That would dictate the answer.

Comment: @epascarello, everyone can read the file

Comment: It can be done on the client side: send the file's content to the client hidden in the html file and than search for the string via javascript.

Comment: http://ejohn.org/blog/dictionary-lookups-in-javascript/

Comment: @Beat: Better yet, just embed the array in a Javascript function.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, do you mean how much time i have to perform this check?  Let's say <10 seconds.

Comment: That make an Ajax call to get the file, look up the data in the file any way you like.

Comment: Well, if you can embed your words list in a Javascript function, at least the browser can cache it, instead of having to send that list each and every time the page is requested.

Comment: Can you send the file contents to the user via HTML and have them use the browser's find feature?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Building a dictionary would take longer than doing a search and if the search string is multiple words then the dictionary would be useless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Synchronously:

```
function checkExists(flatFileUrl, searchString) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET", flatFileUrl, false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    return (xmlhttp.responseText.indexOf(searchString) !== -1);
}
```

I would suggest doing it server side. You don't need a database. Just use your favourite server side language which takes in some parameters and outputs true or false if it finds the search string in the file specified. It will save you some bandwidth.

**Edit**: If you are doing many checks on the file then I would suggest storing the result of the load in an object somewhere... like this:

```
var flatTexts = {};
function checkExists(flatFileUrl, searchString) {
    if (typeof flatTexts[flatFileUrl] === "undefined") {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("GET", flatFileUrl, false);
        xmlhttp.send();
        flatTexts[flatFileUrl] = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
    return (flatTexts[flatFileUrl].indexOf(searchString) !== -1);
}
```